# php add some value on specific location in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array like this

```
Array ([0] => 
    Array (
       [user_id] => 21 
       [email] => momod@modara.com 
       [brand] => Array ( [0] => GOFUEL_W [1] => GOFUEL_USD_W ) ) 
      [1] =>
    Array (
       [user_id] => 22
       [email] => hemisphere@modara.com
       [brand] => Array ( [0] => GOFUEL_W ) )
      [2] =>
    Array (
       [user_id] => 23
       [email] => madoka@modara.com
       [brand] => Array ( [0] => GOFUEL_W [1] => GOFUEL_USD_W [2] => GOFUEL_BGD_W ) ) )
```

i want to locate user_id 22 and put this value "GO_FUEL_SGD_W" on brand, what should i do, so the view of array will look like this

```
Array ([0] => 
    Array (
       [user_id] => 21 
       [email] => momod@modara.com 
       [brand] => Array ( [0] => GOFUEL_W [1] => GOFUEL_USD_W ) ) 
      [1] =>
    Array (
       [user_id] => 22
       [email] => hemisphere@modara.com
       [brand] => Array ( [0] => GOFUEL_W => [1] =>GO_FUEL_SGD_W ) )
      [2] =>
    Array (
       [user_id] => 23
       [email] => madoka@modara.com
       [brand] => Array ( [0] => GOFUEL_W [1] => GOFUEL_USD_W [2] => GOFUEL_BGD_W ) ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple foreach loop will do the job:

```
foreach($myarray AS &$subarray) {
    if($subarray['user_id'] == 22) {
        $subarray['brand'][] = "GO_FUEL_SGD_W";
        break;
    }
}
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/8aQMj

Comment: This will not do the stuff because you'll change only element's __copy__ inside `foreach` loop. Either use `&` or access parent array with index

Comment: @AlmaDo Yup just updated, along with working example

Answer (score 1):

Just use loop:

```
foreach($array as &$item)
{
   if(array_key_exists('user_id', $item) && 
      $item['user_id']==22 &&
      array_key_exists('brand', $item) && 
      !in_array('GO_FUEL_SGD_W', $item['brand']))
   {
      $item['brand'][] = 'GO_FUEL_SGD_W';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to iterate over the array and look for the element you're searching for.

```
foreach ($array as &$element) {
    if ($element['user_id'] != 22)
        continue;

    $element['brand'][] = "GO_FUEL_SGD_W";
    break;
}
```

With [`continue;`](http://www.php.net/continue) all elements will be skipped, who have `$element['user_id'] != 22` (and so none of the code after the `continue;` will be applied to them!).

Also it will end the loop once the requested element is reached and modified, thanks to [`break;`](http://www.php.net/break).

Comment: it ll add to every element in the array

Comment: @Bhadra I guess you missed the `continue` statement in there.

Comment: i think u are missing an else there

Comment: @Bhadra There is no else needed. If the `user_id != 22` it will skip the element (see [`continue`](http://www.php.net/continue)), so everything after the `continue;` will only be applied if the if fails (and `user_id==22`)

Comment: ne ways i have given a +1

Answer (score 0):

```
$array= //your array;
foreach($array as $x){
    if($x['user_id']=='22'){
      $x['brand'][]='GO_FUEL_SGD_W';
      break;
    }

}
```